# Jquery :contains not working properly

Tags: jquery, selector, contains

I'm trying to check to see if a div element contains a certain word and then do something based on wether or not it contains that word.

I am using the :contains selector, but even if I use a word not in the div, it still runs the function. Also if I run an if else, the if always passes no matter if the word is in the div or not.

This is the code I have:

```js
if ( $("#navBreadCrumb a:contains('Apples')") ) {
   console.log('Not Oranges');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navBreadCrumb">
  <a class="bp" href="#">Home</a> &nbsp;::&nbsp;
  <a class="bp" href="#">Fruits</a>&nbsp;::&nbsp;
  <a class="bp" href="#">Citrus</a>&nbsp;::&nbsp;
  <a class="bp" href="#">Oranges</a>&nbsp;::&nbsp;
  Navel Oranges
</div>
```

What am I missing with the :contains selector?

Thank you in advance.

-S

Comment: Because in condition jquery selector alway is true. Use `$("#navBreadCrumb a:contains('Apples')").length > 0`

Comment: Aaahh... got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close. You should use `.length` to check if an element that contains "Apple" exists.

So it should be:

```
if ( $("#navBreadCrumb a:contains('Apples')").length ) {
   console.log('Not Oranges');
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmpa01qb/)

Comment: That did it. Thank you Robin.

Comment: @Sergio Great! Glad it helped.